# Setting title in Instant Analytics GA4

Tags: plugins, craft4, instantanalyticsga4

I’ve installed Instant Analytics GA4 (https://nystudio107.com/docs/instant-analytics-ga4/)

The default title is the template (which is a bizarre default IMO) as a result all of my analytics are reported as landing on "post/_entry.twig".

I’m trying to set the page title as follows:

```
{% set analyticsTitle = entry.title|default("Page") %}
{% do instantAnalytics.setDocumentTitle(analyticsTitle) %}
{% hook 'iaSendPageView' %}
```

but it persists with the template name.

It seems like this should be pretty simple but all the info I can find online is for the previous version of the plugin and suggests the above should work.

Any ideas?

TA